# How can I independently measure the response times for MAPI calls between a workstation and Exchange server?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, rpc

Outlook 2010
Exchange 2010

I'm troubleshooting a delay with an Outlook add-in and in discussing the issue with the add-in vendor support, the available information/symptoms suggest that MAPI call response times may be sluggish.  How can I measure MAPI response times (independently)?  It doesn't have to be the exact same MAPI commands but I'd like to run some general tests.

I was thinking I could use `rpcping` but information on this tool is a little sparse and I wasn't sure what syntax I should use to test connectivity.

Comment: Wireshark and a simple filter?

Comment: Look at the connection status with and without the add-in enabled?

Comment: @EEAA Sorry for not mentioning earlier.  MAPI communication in my environment is encrypted so it's not easy for me to see when specific requests begin/end.

Comment: @joeqwerty I assume you're referring to the `Avg Resp` column values? That might work, but what exactly is that measuring?  From what point to what point?  If I'm using RPC/HTTP would that be the response back from the proxy? Or from Exchange?

Comment: Does it matter? The only thing changing is whether or not the add-in being enabled/disabled makes any difference. It's irrelevant what the endpoint is as that's not changing and that's not what you're testing. You're testing the add-in, not the connection endpoint. In effect, the connection endpoint is your "control" regardless of what it is and is a constant for both tests.

Answer (score 1):

[Enable advanced logging in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2862843). Usually RPC trace events help a lot. Do the following:

1. Disable add-in, collect logs.
2. Enable add-in, collect logs.
3. Review the resulting log files.